# Read T5577 tags with PN532 reader

Tags: rfid, nfc

I am working with adafruit RFID/NFC reader.

This reader works with a PN532 chip.

This chip is designed to read mifare tags (13.56MHz).

I want to read T5577 tags. This tags works at 125 kHz.

I am wondering if PN532 chip can read this tags. I have tried with an Arduino and PN532 library but it does not work.

I want to know if this is a software issue or if PN532 can really not read 125 kHz tags.

If it works with 13.56Mhz, it should work with 125khz tags ("who can do more can do less")

Thanks

Comment: got the same question, I'm looking for a small module for ESP-32 compatible with 125KHz (and 13.56MHz optional)

I wondering if you find and recommend some ? Nowdays most DIY are based on PN53, but can't read simple old NFC business card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [PN532 datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/nxp/data-sheets/PN532_C1.pdf), you’ll see that it is specified to work only at 13.56MHz and only with several specific tag types.

And in fact, a radio circuit for 13 MHz will not automatically work at 125KHz as the tuning is likely to be quite different. This module was designed to work only at one frequency.